# problem with replace string in array python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have problem with replacing a string in array python. when I ran the code, I see the error like this :

```
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-80467a801c45> in <module>
      1 y = []
----> 2 y = localseeding(x , 2)
<ipython-input-158-4ad7d979ab67> in localseeding(x, lsc)
     12                 randomindex = np.random.randint(1 , 15)
     13                 randomrow = np.random.randint(0 , 7)
---> 14                 newtree = [newtree.replace(str(randomnumber), newtree[randomindex][randomrow])]
     15                 #newtree = map(lambda newtree: newtree.replace(str(randomnumber), newtree[randomindex][randomrow]), x)
     16                 newtrees.append(newtree)
>>AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

my code is :

```
y = [0, '11131320', '12010303', '01011101', '22033201', '31110030', '30013321', '30032231', '31131202', '33011201', '31302101', '00313213', '01103101', '23002231', '20311310']

z = [0, '03330223', '02010332', '11131110', '30322202', '10332211', '01220210', '11302310', '03302300', '32121311', '20030313', '03231221', '01302123', '30022200', '03312023']

x = []
x.append(y)
x.append(z)

import numpy as np

def localseeding(x , lsc):
    selectedtree = []
    newtrees = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i][0] == 0 :
            selectedtree.append(i)
            for j in range(len(selectedtree)):
                newtree = x[selectedtree[j]]
                randomnumber = np.random.randint(0 , lsc)
                randomindex = np.random.randint(1 , 15)
                randomrow = np.random.randint(0 , 7)
                newtree = [newtree.replace(str(randomnumber), newtree[randomindex][randomrow])]
                newtrees.append(newtree)
            for t in range(len(x)) :
                x[t][0] +=1
        x.append(newtrees)
        return x 

y = []
y = localseeding(x , 2)
```

I want to replace a new generated random number with one element of one string in an array 
***I want to replace string in one element of '11131320'in newtree:[0, '11131320', '12010303', '01011101', ...'] like replace number 3 in '11131320' so at the end resault is '11331320'

Comment: It says there in the error, a `list` does not have a `replace`method. Use `newtree[index] = value`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Replace the zeros in your string with a randomly generated (string)number?

Comment: @toti08 no I want replace randomnumber variable with one string in position *newtree[randomindex][randomrow]

Comment: Sorry but I really don't get your code...why do you need to define a new list `newtree`?

Comment: @toti08 So what can I do? newtree is Temporary and store the selected array for changing

Comment: @arashaskari can you explain me the `if x[i][0] == 0` statement? Why are you checking the first element of your list?

Comment: @toti08 , this is the condition for do the changes on an array , the only array with zero in the first element can be change in this procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've got your problem entirely, but I just try to summarize what I've understood.
You want to change a random digit inside a randomly selected element of your initial list. Only lists whose first element is `0` should be modified. Once the list has been modified the first element should be incremented so that the list is not modified anymore. You want to return a modified list, which is equal to the input list except for:

- the randomly selected item (where 1 digit will be modified)
- the first element (which will be `1`)

The key point is that you cannot select an element inside a string by indexing it, so you need to convert your string to a list of strings, change your element and then convert it back to a string.
So first you need to select the item you want to modified (which is identified by `randomindex`):

```
element_to_modify = newtree[randomindex]
```

Then you convert this to a list of strings:

```
# Convert element to list of strings
element_to_modify = [e for e in element_to_modify]
```

Output will be something like:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Then you modify the digit, selecting it through `randomrow`:

```
element_to_modify[randomrow] = str(randomnumber)
```

Then you convert this element back to string:

```
modified_element = ''.join([i for i in element_to_modify])
```

And replace this in your list:

```
newtree[randomindex] = modified_element
```

I simplified your code:

```
import numpy as np

y = [0, '11131320', '12010303', '01011101', '22033201', '31110030', '30013321', '30032231', '31131202', '33011201', '31302101', '00313213', '01103101', '23002231', '20311310']
z = [0, '03330223', '02010332', '11131110', '30322202', '10332211', '01220210', '11302310', '03302300', '32121311', '20030313', '03231221', '01302123', '30022200', '03312023']

x = []
x.append(y)
x.append(z)


def localseeding(x , lsc):
    newtrees = []
    print('x', x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i][0] == 0:
            newtree = x[i]               
            randomnumber = np.random.randint(0, lsc)
            randomindex = np.random.randint(1, 15)
            randomrow = np.random.randint(0, 7)
            element_to_modify = newtree[randomindex]
            # Convert element to list of strings
            element_to_modify = [e for e in element_to_modify]
            element_to_modify[randomrow] = str(randomnumber)
            # Convert back to string
            modified_element = ''.join([i for i in element_to_modify])
            # Replace modified element in original list
            newtree[randomindex] = modified_element
            newtrees.append(newtree)          
            x[i][0] += 1
    return newtrees


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = localseeding(x, 2)
```

Output:

```
[1, '11131320', '12000303', '01011101', '22033201', '31110030', '30013321', '30032231', '31131202', '33011201', '31302101', '00313213', '01103101', '23002231', '20311310']
[1, '03330223', '02010332', '11131110', '30322202', '10332211', '01220210', '11302310', '03302300', '32121311', '20030313', '03231221', '01302123', '30022200', '03312023']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, This really helps to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

According to you code, in the first cycle the loop, `newtree` will be the `y`.

so the `newtree` is :`[0, '11131320', '12010303', '01011101', ...']`

you have generated a 3 random values, `index`, `value` and `row`.

So I think you want to change that random index value to random value.

in that case you can simply do this:

```
newtree[randomindex] = randomnumber
```

That will change a random index value to the new number, but I do not understand the usage of the `row` here.

Comment: I want to replace randomnumber in one of the element in string like that : newtree[randminindex][randomrow] = randomnumber

Comment: Can you make an example of your expected output?